# How to remove part of a string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to change a list of strings by keeping only the beginning and end of the strings and removing the middle.

I want to keep:

1. **first name + <kbd>space</kbd>**
   first word of the string
2. **last initial + <kbd>space</kbd>**
   first letter of the second word
3. **<kbd>-</kbd> + reason for the absence**
   the dash and everything that follows it

I have managed to get part-way and have tried TRIM and REGEXREPLACE but need help getting the desired output with a formula.

Please see below.  My initial strings are in column A and the outcome I want is in column 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Formula in B2

```
  =LEFT(A2, FIND(" ",A2)+1)&" "&
   RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+1)
```

##### Sample Output

```
  |--------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------|
1 | INPUT                                                  | OUTPUT                   |
  |--------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------|
2 | Alex Hill will be 1 day on a leave - Holidays          | Alex H - Holidays        |
  |--------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------|
3 | Anna Low will be 273 days on a leave - Maternity leave | Anna L - Maternity leave |
  |--------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------|
4 | Frank Tibbs will be 2 days on a leave - Holidays       | Frank T - Holidays       |
  |--------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------|
5 | Matthew Small will be 4 days on a leave - Holidays     | Matthew S - Holidays     |
  |--------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------|
6 | Simon Wright will be 5 days on a leave - Holidays      | Simon W - Holidays       |
  |--------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------|
```

Comment: I have another Q (sorry)
If the above 5 lines of data were in 1 cell (with line breaks)....
Is it possible to put a funky formula into B2 so that the output will be same (as in 5 lines in 1 cell)?