# Formula to extract parts of a multi-line string in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have am using a formula that extracts part of a text string from a cell in Google Sheets based on this [answer to an earlier question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168072/).

The formula is `=LEFT(A2, FIND(" ", A2)+1)&" "&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+1)` where `A2` is a reference to my source text.

Example Output with formula in `B2`

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **2** | Alex Hill will be 1 day on a leave - Holidays | Alex H - Holidays |

This works when each string is in a separate row, but I have a number of lines of data in the same cell and the formula will only work on the the first line of text.

Example with same formula in `B2` and a multi-line string in `A2`

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **2** | Alex Hill will be 1 day on a leave - Holidays Frank Tibbs will be 2 days on a leave - Holidays Matthew Small will be 4 days on a leave - Holidays Simon Wright will be 5 days on a leave - Holidays Anna Low will be 273 days on a leave - Maternity leave | Alex H - Holidays |

Is there a similar formula that would do the same job but for each and every line in a multi-line cell with the the formula result also being a multi-line cell?

This is an example of what I want to see in `B2` based on a multi-line string in `A2`

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **2** | Alex Hill will be 1 day on a leave - Holidays Frank Tibbs will be 2 days on a leave - Holidays Matthew Small will be 4 days on a leave - Holidays Simon Wright will be 5 days on a leave - Holidays Anna Low will be 273 days on a leave - Maternity leave | Alex H - Holidays Frank T - Holidays Matthew S - Holidays Simon W - Holidays Anna L - Maternity leave |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A1` contains the text, this may be a solution:

```
=join(char(10),byrow(transpose(split(A1,char(10))),lambda(r,left(r,find(" ",r)+1)&right(r,len(r)-find("-",r)+2))))
```

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ELQUaZ2nZc6vEy0x3CujTnG1ZzF07CDC1Rq-Vt63v4A/edit?usp=sharing) to a test file

Answer (score 1):

Your [original question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168072/) had a single line of data in each row and you were seeking a single line of data in the formula result.  Your new question has multiple lines of data joined in a single cell with a line break `char(10)` as delimiter and you'd like the output to have a similar format.

In order to adapt the original formula, you must first change the source data from multiple lines in one row, to a single line in multiple rows then after applying the formula to each row in turn, you will need to change the resulting output from multiple single line rows back into a single row with multiple lines.

[@Daniele](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/284743/daniele) correctly adapted my formula for your new use case first and should be credited with [the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168188/197518).

Understanding the steps will better allow you to adapt them to other formulas.

1. Split the Data into multiple rows at the line break character [char(10)].
   <sub>=SPLIT(text, delimiter, [split_by_each], [remove_empty_text]))</sub>

```
  =SPLIT(A1,char(10))
```

2. Transpose the resulting array of columns into an array of rows.
   Following this step, your data layout will now mimic the layout of the data in your [original question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/168071).
   <sub>=TRANSPOSE(array_or_range)</sub>

```
  =TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,char(10)))
```

3. Convert the original formula into a LAMBDA function
   <sub>=LAMBDA([name, …], formula_expression)</sub>

```
  =LEFT(A1, FIND(" ", A1)+1)&" "& 
        RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("-", A1)+1)

  // becomes 

  =LAMBDA(x, LEFT(x, FIND(" ", x)+1)& " "&
                  RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-FIND("-", x)+1))

  //  `x` as `name` is an arbitrary choice, you can
  //  replace by a a different letter or word.
```

4. Use BYROW to apply the LAMBDA function to the array of rows created in ***#2*** above.
   Following this step, the layout of the formula result will now mimic the output layout in your [original question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/168071).
   <sub>=BYROW(array_or_range, lambda)</sub>

```
  =BYROW( TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,char(10))), 
          LAMBDA(x, LEFT(x, FIND(" ", x)+1)& " "& 
                          RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-FIND("-", x)+1)))
```

5. Finally, JOIN the resulting array from ***#4*** above into a single cell using the line break character as delimiter.
   <sub>=JOIN(delimiter, value_or_array1, [value_or_array2, …])</sub>

```
  =JOIN(char(10), BYROW(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,char(10))),
                         LAMBDA(x, LEFT(x, FIND(" ", x)+1)& " "&
                                RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-FIND("-", x)+1))))

  // or simply

  =JOIN(char(10), BYROW(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,char(10))), LAMBDA(x, LEFT(x, FIND(" ", x)+1)& " "&RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-FIND("-", x)+1))))
```

##### Variations

The steps above assume that your array is 1x1 (1 Row x 1 Col).  There is no reason the array couldn't be 3x1, 100x1, or (n)x1 if you adapt the step **#1** to first JOIN the range with a line break delimiter.  This would work as well for 1x1 as for (n)x1 So, if useful,

6. (new #1) JOIN all rows in range delimited by line break, then SPLIT the data into rows at the line break character [char(10)].

```
  // Instead of 
  
  =SPLIT(A1,char(10))

  // use
  =SPLIT(JOIN(char(10), A1), char(10))

  // which changes the final formula to

  =JOIN(char(10), BYROW(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(char(10), A1), char(10))),
                         LAMBDA(x, LEFT(x, FIND(" ", x)+1)& " "&
                                RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-FIND("-", x)+1))))

  // In this variation, A1 could also be A1:A10 or A:A
```

7. (skip step #4) As mentioned in step **#4**, if you stopped there, regardless if your data was a line per row or multiple lines in one or more rows, you would at this point have output that gave you one line per row.

```
 =BYROW(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(char(10), A1), char(10))),
                         LAMBDA(x, LEFT(x, FIND(" ", x)+1)& " "&
                                RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-FIND("-", x)+1)))
```

---

#### Screenshots

<kbd>Step 1</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>Step 2</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>Step 4</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>Step 5</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>Step 6 (Variation)</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>Step 7 (Variation)</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts :)